# Accessing Array in Loop Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a vector that is for example: [ 0, 4, 5, 1 , 2, 3]

What I want is to go through the vector and assign in this way:

1st iteration: a = 0; b = 4; c = 5;

2nd iteration: a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;

and so on..

I tried this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Vec.size() - 2; i+=3) {

  for (int j = i + 1; j < Vec.size() - 1; j+=3) {

      for (int k = j + 1; k < Vec.size(); k+=3) {

      area = triangle_area_calculator(Vec.get(i), Vec.get(j), Vec.get(k));

      }
  }
```

}

But of course this only work in the first iteration and it gets messed up in the second.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a single for loop, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Vec.size() - 2; i+=3) {
area = triangle_area_calculator(Vec.get(i), Vec.get(i+1), Vec.get(i+2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 2; i < Vec.size(); i+=3) {
    area = triangle_area_calculator(Vec.get(i), Vec.get(i - 1), Vec.get(i - 2));
}
```

You could do something like this...